# Devexpress chart don't respond when scrolling range is set

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

Question about Devexpress xtra chart for winforms
In some cases application don't respond when I call function

```
myChart.diagram.AxisX.Range.ScrollingRange.SetMinMaxValues(startRange, finishRange);
```

The type of diagram is XYdiagram
ScaleType of x-axis is dateTime and all series has this scaleType
startRange and finishRange are correct

Comment: Are you getting any error message?

Comment: Why don't you contact DX directly?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the Range to auto as so (My DevX is kind of old so the class names/methods may have changed some)

```
myChart.diagram.AxisX.Range.Auto = false;
```

Comment: this field is set to false by default